# Entity Framework - Delete join table record when one linked record is deleted

Tags: entity-framework-6, many-to-many

```
public class Club
{
    public int ClubId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
}

public class Membership
{
    public int ClubId { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public Club Club { get; set; }
    public Person Person { get; set; }
}`

...

modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Memberships)
    .WithRequired(m => m.Person)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Above is a simple set up of two independent entities: Club and Person, which may be joined via membership.

I had thought that I could simply retrieve a Person, delete it, and then rely on cascade deleting to remove any Membership records and leave the associated Clubs in place (they exist independently).

Similarly, I had thought that I could simply retrieve a Club, delete it, and then rely on cascade deleting to remove amy Membership records and leave the associated Persons in place (they exist independently).

It seems that when I remove a "Person", EF tries to set the value of Membership.PersonId to null causing a db violation.

Have I misunderstood cascade deleting?  And how could I achieve the desired result?

I guess that I could retrieve Person.Include("Membership") and then enumerate each membership and mark as deleted and then finally mark the Person as deleted ... but is this really required or am I missing a trick?

Comment: Should cascade delete alright. I assume Membership is configured as having primary key `ClubId + PersonId`?

Comment: Thanks, @GertArnold.  That forced me look elsewhere.  I had a Context which I used to insert some data in a transaction.  Commit that.   Then start a new transaction on the same context to retrieve object and mark as deleted and savechanges.  Turns out when I re-"new"ed the Context before doing the retrieval, mark as deleted, save changes step ... all was fine.  Something to do with Entity tracking and states not working as I thought, I guess.